# How to get picture to align with the left set of paragraphs/go to right of?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend, user-experience

Here is a prototype of what I am trying to implement 
[image]

Here is what I currently have :  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lasred/uggopbhk/1/)
[image]

I am trying to get the picture of the guy on the laptop to align correctly with and to the right of the paragraph components - Business Traveller, Office Supply Purchases, etc...

What I've tried is using  [Align](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp) attribute, changing my img src code to

```
<img id="laptop" align="middle" src="zoom-39988392-3.JPG" height = "90" width ="90" />
```

but that didn't have any effect.
I also tried [Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002228/floating-picture-to-right-of-p-within-a-div) but that messed up my margins and the organization of my left components.

Is there a way I can do this without floating?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/uggopbhk/5/) what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/uggopbhk/5/)

The HTML and CSS that i've used is as follows. Used `float:left`

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="choices">
        <p class="choice">Business Traveller</p>
        <p class="choice">Office Supply Purchases</p>
        <p class="choice">Stay at home parent</p>
        <p class="choice">Entertainment</p>
        <p class="choice">Profile 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, .container {
    height:100%;
}
#choices {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
.choice {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/H43sVoi.png");
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
.image {
    height:100%;
    width:65%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
```

You will have to work with the height and width of each divs. I just made it roughly.

Comment: Is it better to use table/cols like what @webcodecs said?

Comment: @committedandroider It is better to use div structure then table. Check http://jsfiddle.net/uggopbhk/7/

Comment: I dont think using table for this is not a good idea..I think what @webcodecs suggested was to use a two-column layout in which the 1st column contains the navigation and the second column contains the image.

Comment: Yes, i meant a 2 column layout with floating divs. Please do not use tables for layouting.

Comment: @ketan This is more of a concept question but I know that height and width are with respective to the block element, in this case the div. How did you get the div that contains the laptop picture to stretch to that much? I saw that you used vertical align but that only sets the vertical aligment - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Can you guys take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106602/how-to-make-image-stretch-to-a-specific-paragraph/30107373#30107373   It's based off this question

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two columns. 1 column for the menu and the second column for the image. If you do this, you wont have trouble floating.